# How can I speed up xaml creation in VS 2008?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008

Ok I know about XAML Power Toys, and thats pretty cool, but still kind of cumbersome for me. I like code snippets in the C# code view, but I can't don't know how to do that in xaml designer.

What other options do I have?

Is there a simple way to add maybe code snippets? Instead of typing out all the column and row definitions of a grid.

Can I extend the xaml designer? How would I start that?

Should I try create an add-in like Xaml Power Toys that fits more my style?

Any ideas?

Comment: An add-in might be overkill -- have you looked at Visual Studio macros?

Comment: Never knew about VS macros. It's awesome!!! Just what I need in a couple scenarios. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options as I see it:

1. Use Expression Blend or XAMLPad to do your editing.
2. Download VS 2010 Beta 2

Sorry I can't offer anything better, but that's where we are at.

Answer (score 1):

I certainly wouldn't start writing an addin for VS2008 at this point because VS2010 has major improvements that would make it a lot easier to do and with better results.

In the meantime, one easy improvement is to stop VS2008 loading the designer whenever you open a XAML file; this can save a lot of time if you do most of your XAML editing by hand or are using Blend, Kaxaml or another visual editor alongside VS2008.

To do this, open the *Options* window, go to *Text Editor - XAML - Miscellaneous* and enable the *Always open documents in full XAML view* option.

Comment: I had to go one step further and always open XAML files as raw XML. I am really looking forward to using VS 2010 on production work.